# java: las posiciones decimales no se modifican

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un mod para minecraft y tengo una clase con la que manejo las animaciones y al momento
de querer modificar las variables siempre tienen su valor por defecto, cuando estoy en la funcion tick
y quiero imprimir el valor de la variable change me dice que es 0 pero yo le estoy asigando otro valor,
incluso intente sumarle a aty el valor directamente y sigue sin modificarse,espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

```
public class ASVALModel extends GunModel{

public float atx, aty, atz;
public final float change;

public static ModelResourceLocation HAMMER = new ModelResourceLocation(ItemRegistries.asval.get().getRegistryName() + "_hammer", "inventory");
public static ModelResourceLocation MAG = new ModelResourceLocation(ItemRegistries.asval.get().getRegistryName() + "_mag", "inventory");

public ASVALModel(IBakedModel model, int fire, int reload,float tx, float ty, float tz) {
    super(model, fire, reload,tx, ty, tz);
    atx = 0;
    aty = 0;
    atz = 0;
    change = 100/(50*200);
}

@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)
public void doArmAnimation(ItemStack stack, MatrixStack matrix) {
    matrix.rotate(new Quaternion((float)Math.toRadians(rx), (float)Math.toRadians(ry), (float)Math.toRadians(rz), false));
    matrix.translate(atx, aty, atz);
}

@Override
public void tick(ItemStack stack, PlayerEntity player) {
    super.tick(stack, player);
    if(reload > 0) {
        System.out.println("aty: " + this.aty + "change: " + this.change);
        if(aty > -0.6875) {
            aty -= change;
            System.out.println("--");
        }else {
                System.out.println("aty == -0.6875");
                if(atz > -0.140625) {
                    atz -= change;
                }
                if(atx < 0.359375) {
                    atx += change;
                }else {
                if(atz > -0.40625) {
                    atz -= change;
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        if(atz < -0.140625) {
            atz += change;
        }else {
            if(atx > 0) {
                atx -= change;
            }else {
                if(atz < 0) {
                    atz += change;
                }
                if(aty < 0) {
                    aty += change;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui les dejo lo que me sale cuando imprimo las variables

> [m[32m[12:14:51] [Server thread/INFO] [STDOUT/]: [com.jg.guns.client.models.ASVALModel:tick:56]: aty: 0.0change: 0.0

> [m[32m[12:14:52] [Server thread/INFO] [STDOUT/]: [com.jg.guns.client.models.ASVALModel:tick:59]: --

Comment: de casualidad usas forge?

Comment: Si, hago mods para minecraft

Comment: jejej bueno me referia en el codigo de l apregunta para ponerle la etiqueta correspondiente :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en la operación `100/(50*200)` solo hay enteros, por lo que de su resultado se tomará la parte entera en este caso `0`.

La solución es hacer que uno de los operandos sea float:

```
change = 100f/(50*200);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me salvaste